# Convert Blanks to NA in Sparse Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix that I'm reading into R and converting to a matrix with the following code

```
gt <-readMM("matrix.mtx")
gt_0 <- as.matrix(gt)
```

However, the blank fields that are within the `gt` object are converted to 0 during the `gt_0 <- as.matrix(gt)` call.

The problem is that the actual values of my matrix are binary (0|1) so filling with 0 makes downstream analyses impossible.

I would like blanks to be filled with NA if possible not 0

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: I'm not sure what format `readMM` returns, but could you use `gt[gt == ""] <- NA` to replace them with NA before calling `as.matrix()`?

Comment: Unfortunately `gt ` is a `Formal class 'dgTMatrix' [package "Matrix"]` and this function cannot be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `0`s with `NA`s *after* you convert from `dgTMatrix` to `matrix`

```
# Sample data
library(Matrix)
gt <- Matrix(0+1:28, nrow = 4)
gt[-3,c(2,4:5,7)] <- gt[ 3, 1:4] <- gt[1:3, 6] <- 0
gt <- as(m, "dgTMatrix")

# Convert to matrix and replace 0s with NAs
gt_0 <- as.matrix(gt)
gt_0[gt_0 == 0] <- NA
gt_0
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    1   NA    9   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    2   NA   10   NA   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   19   NA   27
#[4,]    4   NA   12   NA   NA   24   NA
```

Comment: As I said above "The problem is that the actual values of my matrix are binary (0|1) so filling with 0 makes downstream analyses impossible." This would mean that I'd not only convert what used to be blanks to NA but also my actual values that are 0. This is a very important distinction in my dataset.

Comment: @StephenWilliams Hmm. I don't think you quite understand the concept of sparse matrices. The idea is to only store non-zero entries, while zero-entries are considered empty. So in your words: *"the blank fields that are within the gt object are converted to 0"* because that's what they are: they are zero by definition of a sparse matrix. If zero entries actually encode a response (or rather the absence of one) you shouldn't use a sparse matrix.

Comment: I do understand the concept of a sparse matrix and this is why the problem is difficult (and seemingly not answered anywhere). I am not personally writing this sparse matrix it is another developer and because of naming conventions in our industry 0 is used for this type of data. It is unfortunate, I know. If my only option is to have him rewrite how his software writes the sparse matrix I will do so.